# reorder a vector to first, last, second, second last, etc

Tags: r

Is there actually an easy solution to reordering a vector like
first element, last element, second element, second last element, etc.

So I expect for `c(1,2,3,4,5)` to get `c(1,5,2,4,3)`.

The reason is I have a color palette with 16 colours and color 1 is very similar to two but not to color 16. But within my plots, the dots coloured by color 1 are close to the ones are coloured by color 2.

For my color palette I use Set 1 from color brewer and also use `colorRampPalette` to calculate colours in between, so they get a bit similar.

One solution would be to just `sample(my_colors)` but actually I would like to reorder them like I told above.

Comment: `rbind(x,rev(x))[1:length(x)]`

Comment: Awesome solution! Please post and answer so I can accept! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- rbind(a,a[5:1])
c <-b [1:5]
```

Hope this helps

Here is a [fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=3uiWXQRr)

You can generalise this with

```
rbind(a,rev(a))[1:length(a)]
```

Comment: Here is another approach to this solution, but more easily generalizable (that is no hard coded lengths):


`a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- rbind(a,rev(a))
c <-b [1:length(a)]`

Comment: The comment was posted while I was making the fiddle.  I only read it after my post.  The comment is a better answer though, since it is more general (upvoted it).

Comment: @R.Schifini; agreed, they are posted at much the same time, but regardless it doesnt matter. Feel free to update with the generalisation if you wish

Comment: @user20650, please post your comment as an answer. I am already happy to have reached a similar approach as you (and I am new to R)

Comment: Since all are happy with the solution here I will give R. Schifini the credit... Thanks again for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy way to do this:

```
a<-seq(1,100)
b<-a-median(a)
names(a)=b
a<-order(-abs(b))



   print(a)
  [1]   1 100   2  99   3  98   4  97   5  96   6  95   7  94   8  93   9  92  10  91  11  90  12  89  13  88  14  87
 [29]  15  86  16  85  17  84  18  83  19  82  20  81  21  80  22  79  23  78  24  77  25  76  26  75  27  74  28  73
 [57]  29  72  30  71  31  70  32  69  33  68  34  67  35  66  36  65  37  64  38  63  39  62  40  61  41  60  42  59
 [85]  43  58  44  57  45  56  46  55  47  54  48  53  49  52  50  51
```

From the comments:

**1: From @bgoldst: A better (one line) approach that doesn't involve vector names:**

```
a[order(-abs(a-median(a)))]
```

**2: (Also from bgoldst) For dealing with non-numeric (alphabetical order) values:**

```
letters[order(-abs(seq_along(letters)-(length(letters)+1)/2))]
```

Comment: ➕1 Brilliant. But why mess with vector names? Can do it in one line with `a[order(-abs(a-median(a)))]`.

Comment: And maybe something like `letters[order(-abs(seq_along(letters)-(length(letters)+1)/2))]` for generality to work with non-numeric inputs.